# Using Data annotation in Model for DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, format-string

I am using following code to popup calendar  for **date** in my razor view

**Model**

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndTime { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now I want to use **DateTime** instead of Date.What should be the DataFormat String?

**My Try**

```
Display(Name = "End Date Time")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}{1:HH/mm}")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
```

I am getting format exception?

Comment: Did you try simply _DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")]_?

Comment: Yes I did use but in this case the calendar does not pop up at all.

Comment: What are you using to display the calendar?  Is that bootstrap?

Comment: I have written View code also please see that.

Comment: Is it Chrome's calendar or some plugin like bootstrap, jquery-ui?

Comment: Please see my View code ......I did not use any calendar like that in bootstrap

Comment: If your wanting the HTML-5 datetimepicker, then you need to use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndTime, "{0:s}", new { @type = "datetime-local", @class = "form-control" })`. But note that its only supported in recent versions of Chrome and Edge

Comment: Thanks Stephen you saved me.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `EditorFor()` method renders an input with `type="date"` because of the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute, which will generate the browsers HTML-5 datepicker (but this is only supported in Chrome and Edge).

To generate a HTML-5 datetimepicker, you need to render an input with `type = "datetime-local"` but there is no data annotation attribute for that. Instead you need to generate the `type` attribute yourself.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndTime, "{0:s}", new { @type = "datetime-local", @class = "form-control" })
```

Note `"{0:s}"` is shortcut for `"{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss}"` and will display the date and time in the browsers culture. Note also that you do not need your `[DataType]` attribute or the `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` property in the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute since they apply only to `EditorFor()`